# Python datetime utcnow does not set timezone?

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, utc

Found this issues working with timestamp conversions where the `.timestamp()` seem to compensate for time offset even though I created the datetime object with `utcnow()` method. So what is the reason for the `utcnow()` method if it actually fails when converting to timestamp later on?

```py
def test_timestamp_issues():
    now = datetime.now()
    utc_now = datetime.utcnow()
    utc_now_with_tz = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
    print(f"Now: {now} -- As Timestamp: {now.timestamp()}")
    print(f"Utc Now: {utc_now} -- As TimeStamp: {utc_now.timestamp()} "
          f"with builtin: {datetime.timestamp(utc_now)}, with setting timezone hard: "
          f"{utc_now.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()}")
    print(f"Utc Now: {utc_now_with_tz} -- As TimeStamp: {utc_now_with_tz.timestamp()} "
          f"with builtin: {datetime.timestamp(utc_now_with_tz)}, with setting timezone hard: "
          f"{utc_now_with_tz.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()}")
```

Output:

```sh
Now: 2022-04-25 09:12:16.881608 -- As Timestamp: 1650870736.881608
Utc Now: 2022-04-25 07:12:16.881613 -- As TimeStamp: 1650863536.881613 with builtin: 1650863536.881613, with setting timezone hard: 1650870736.881613
Utc Now: 2022-04-25 07:12:16.881753+00:00 -- As TimeStamp: 1650870736.881753 with builtin: 1650870736.881753, with setting timezone hard: 1650870736.881753
```

The expected timestamp here should be *1650870736.881608* but for some reason converting the utcnow() gives 2 hours backward again.

So for some reason I get another 2 hours withdrawal when taking timestamp of a `utcnow()` created datetime object. I am currently running a macbook m1 pro, with Timezone Norway (+1, +2 atm with daylight), and python 3.9.12

So can this be the arm architecture messing up things or is it just not recommended to use the `utcnow()` and then convert to timestamp?

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature. And you're not the first one that finds this confusing: [stop using utcnow](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/utcnow.html). Use `datetime.now(timezone.utc)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is managing timezones (TZ). When you create a `datetime` instance with `now()` or `utcnow()`, it does not store info about TZ. And, according to python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow) for `utcnow()` (bolding by author):

> Return the current UTC date and time, with **`tzinfo` None**.
>
> This is like `now()`, but returns the current UTC date and time, as a **naive `datetime` object**. An aware current UTC datetime can be obtained by calling `datetime.now(timezone.utc)`. See also `now()`.
>
> **Warning**: Because **naive `datetime` objects are treated by many datetime methods as local times**, it is preferred to use aware datetimes to represent times in UTC. As such, the recommended way to create an object representing the current time in UTC is by calling `datetime.now(timezone.utc)`.

This means that, although you received time for UTC TZ with `utcnow()`, since no TZ info is stored (naive `datetime` object), python thinks of it as a local time. And, when converting it to timestamp, will add/subtract time difference once again. Proof for this weird behaviour may be found in python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) for `timestamp()` method:

> Naive `datetime` instances are assumed to represent local time

The reason actually is the one, you stated in the title of the question, not the ARM architecture